# Main app assets catalog copied in today extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, today-extension

When I added a Today Extension my app suddenly gained a lot of weight... so I did a rapid checkup to see where that fat is coming from. It look like the .apex is 13MB, the 'Assets.car' file is the even bigger than the one in my main app (+8MB). The thing is, I use only 1 image in the assets catalog I have in my extension.

I checked within Xcode, my main app assets catalog is not toggled to be copied with the extension, but it sounds like it is in fact.

Is it normal? Do you know what to do in order to reduce the final .apex size?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing this, too. Main app has an `assets.car` of 4MB. Even after removing all assets from the ext, it remains 16MB.

Comment: Yep, my widget assets.car is even bigger than my main app one.

Comment: We're seeing this too.  We don't even use many assets in our extensions.  Has anyone figured out how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you by any chance using [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org)?

There's currently an [open issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1546) that causes the `Copy Pods Resources` run script to locate all assets and compile them into a big archive, which might not be desired for all targets.

Until this is fixed, a simple solution is to add a `post_install` hook to your `Podfile`:

```
# Fix broken copy-resources phase per https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1546.
post_install do |installer|
  installer.project.targets.each do |target|
    scriptBaseName = "\"Pods/Target Support Files/#{target.name}/#{target.name}-resources\""
    sh = (<<-EOT)
      if [ -f #{scriptBaseName}.sh ]; then
        if [ ! -f #{scriptBaseName}.sh.bak ]; then
          cp #{scriptBaseName}.sh #{scriptBaseName}.sh.bak;
        fi;
        sed '/WRAPPER_EXTENSION/,/fi\\n/d' #{scriptBaseName}.sh > #{scriptBaseName}.sh.temp;
        sed '/*.xcassets)/,/;;/d' #{scriptBaseName}.sh.temp > #{scriptBaseName}.sh;
        rm #{scriptBaseName}.sh.temp;
      fi;
    EOT
    `#{sh}`
  end
end
```

*Credit for the above code snippet goes to all the helpful people in the issue thread!*

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot! I should have looked at the Cocoapods level. Went from 28 mb to 19!